# Custom Post Types set up, how do I style the main slug page?

Tags: theme-development

So basically I have custom post types set up, and one of these is called Packages. It's for a web design/SEO company. I need the nav link Packages to show in the navigation and all of the child links for the link Packages will be all of the posts inside the Packages custom post type. If that's too confusing, just tell me and I can explain more.

What I need to know is how can I make the posts in the Packages custom post type to show as the child pages of the Products page.

Any way this can be done? Preferably with PHP or jQuery.

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
    $pages = get_pages('parent=0'); 
    foreach ($pages as $pagg) { $key = 'childpages'; $id = get_the_ID();
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'products' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if(get_post_meta($id, $key, true) == 'products') :
        $option = '<li><a href="'.get_page_link($page->ID).'">';
        $option .= $pagg->post_title;
        $option .= '</a>';
        $option .= '<ul class="children"';
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $option .= '<li>';
            $option .= the_title();
            $option .= '</li>';
        endwhile;
        $option .= '</ul></li>';
    else : 
        $option = '<li><a href="'.get_page_link($page->ID).'">';
        $option .= $pagg->post_title;
        $option .= '</a></li>';
    endif;
    echo $option; }
?>
```

If the page has a custom field of `childpages` with the value `products`, display them as the child pages. Will this even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @**Jared**

One idea is to look at the [`'rewrite'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) argument for custom post types.

You can also create a `[shortcode]` and create a page in your functions.php file for displaying the Packages.

Comment: This actually lead me to a better solution, I didn't think about using custom menus. Thanks. :)